# How can I change the production status via code? (AX 2009)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, ax

I have to change the production status via code, but not from the ProdTable form. The problem that I have is, that the class ProdMultiRelease expects to be run from the ProdTable form.
(Line 10: RunBaseMultiParm::initFromForm(prodMultiRelease,args);)

**Update:**
Here are some additional informations. First I tried it with something like this:

```
static void Job1(Args _args)
{
    Args args;
    ProdTable prodTable;
    ;
    prodTable = ProdTable::find( 'PRD_00005166', true);
    args = new Args();
    args.record( prodTable );
    new MenuFunction( menuitemactionstr( ProdRelease ), MenuItemType::Action ).run( args );
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Now I have something like this:

```
static void startprod(Args _args)
{
    ProdTable           prodTable;
    ProdMultiStartUp    ProdMultiStartUp;
    ;
    prodTable.selectForUpdate(true);
    select prodTable where prodTable.ProdId =='0267_074';
    prodTable.ProdStatus = prodStatus::StartedUp;
    prodTable.update();
    info('done');
}
```

This works fine, but I don't know if there are problems with simply setting the status.

**Update2:**
I think I'll do it with:

```
prodTable.autoUpdate(prodStatus::Released);
```

Comment: To be more precise, I'd like to update a production order to release.

Comment: If you found an answer yourself, post it and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way is to do it with:

```
prodTable.autoUpdate(prodStatus::Released);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem while executing this code. The following code worked for me:

```
static void setProdStatusStarted(Args _args)
{
    ProdUpdStartUp      prodUpdStartUp;
    ProdParmStartUp     prodParmStartUp;
    ProdParametersDim   prodParametersDim;
    ProdTable           prodTable;

    ProdId              prodId = "PROD-0001";

    prodTable = ProdTable::find(prodId);

    ttsBegin;
    prodParmStartUp.initValue();
    prodParmStartUp.initParmDefault();

    prodParametersDim = ProdParametersDim::find(prodTable.InventDimId);

    prodParmStartUp.initFromProdParametersDim(prodParametersDim);
    prodParmStartUp.ProdId = prodTable.ProdId;
    prodParmStartUp.PostNowBOM = NoYes::No;
    //CompletePickListJournal property allows it to create additional picking list journals which are missing for the BOM.
    prodParmStartUp.CompletePickListJournal = NoYes::Yes;

    prodParmStartUp.insert();
    ttsCommit;

    prodUpdStartUp = ProdUpdStartUp::construct();
    prodUpdStartUp.parmParmBuffer(prodParmStartUp);
    prodUpdStartUp.run();
}
```

[Check this blog](https://axlog.wordpress.com/2016/03/31/update-production-order-status-to-started-via-code-x-in-ax-2012/)

Comment: Which AX version are you using?

Comment: Version: AX 2012 R3 CU9